# User is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:CreateStack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying out [Serverless](http://serverless.com) to create AWS Lambdas and while creating a project using the command `serverless project create` I'm getting the following error.

```
AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/XXXXXXXXX is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:CreateStack on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXX:stack/XXXXXXXXX-development-r/*
```

I have created a user and granted the following permissions to the user.

1. AWSLambdaFullAccess
2. AmazonS3FullAccess
3. CloudFrontFullAccess
4. AWSCloudFormationReadOnlyAccess ( There was no `AWSCloudFormationFullAccess` to grant )

How can I proceed? What else permissions I have to grant?

Comment: As of 26th July 2019 there is now a `AWSCloudFormationFullAccess` policy.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The closest one that you've mentioned is `AWSCloudFormationReadOnlyAccess`, but obviously that's for readonly and you need `cloudformation:CreateStack`. Add the following as a **user policy**.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1449904348000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CreateStack"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It's entirely possible you'll need more permissions- for instance, to launch an EC2 instance, to (re)configure security groups, etc.

Comment: How can I grant `cloudformation:CreateStack`? I'm using the AWS UI not CLI.

Comment: You paste the text I gave in as a custom user policy.

Comment: You can use Aws Policy Generator to generate this concrete policy or any other

Comment: I find it so odd that this is not available through their drag and drop UI, thanks.

Comment: I followed your instructions and added that as an inline policy, but now I get a similar error when I try to run describe-stacks.  How do I modify this policy to allow describe-stacks?

Comment: @pixelwiz get used to adding permissions. [here's the list for cloudformation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_cloudformation.html).

Comment: @pixelwiz you can add `cloudformation:*` to include all permissions. Also for me there is a UI now to create these Inline Policies.

Comment: Really useful. Thanks

Answer (score 38):

What @tedder42 said, but I also had to add the following to my group policy before I could deploy to lambda from inside visual studio.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1449904348000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ListStacks",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You'd need `cloudformation:DescribeStacks` as well if you plan on doing `servlerless info`.

Comment: This answer should be upvoted and +1 to @pdeschen saying you also need to add `cloudformation:DescribeStacks` if you're trying to deploy with serverless. I also had to add `cloudformation:DescribeStackResource`, `cloudformation:ValidateTemplate`

Comment: I also added these 2 actions :
    cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents
    cloudformation:DeleteStack
because I needed to permit, my users delete the stacks as well.

Answer (score 8):

In my recent experience the policy required was

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1449904348000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ListStacks",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
                "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I wasn't able to get the shorter versions shown above to work; what fixed things for me was extending @mancvso 's answer slightly to add `"cloudformation:GetTemplateSummary"`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1449904348000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ListStacks",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
                "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplateSummary"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It will be more helpful if you mention what is the difference. Only GetTemplateSummary?

Comment: Really useful. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

if you have multiple AWS profiles, try to explicity

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<value>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<value>
```

before trying

```
serverless deploy
```

Comment: This was the quickest solution!

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this issue by adding the permission to the user in the AWS console:

1. Go to AWS Console
2. Find the user whose credentials you are using IAM > Access Management > Users
3. Permissions > 'Add Permissions' > 'Attach existing policies directly'
4. Search for and select 'AWSCloudFormationFullAccess'

Comment: Easiest answer. Does exactly as the above but very succinctly

Comment: I had to wait a minute after adding the policy until the issue was solved on the CLI.

Answer (score 2):

These 2 helped me cross the line...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "apigateway:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:ListStacks",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for others reference in case s/he was searching the issue and get here:

**Make sure that you deleted the permissions boundary for that IAM user.**

If you found that you have granted the cloudformation full access to the IAM user and still get the same error claiming `User is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:CreateStack`, then it's denied by the permissions boundary.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, goto https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-west-1#/roles
and enter AWSAmplifyExecutionRole-xxxxx, then click "Attach policies" button, and search "AWSCloudFormationFullAccess" and add this permison to the amplify role

Answer (score 1):

Create the following policy:

1. Click on Policy -> Create Policy
2. Under Select Service - Type EKS & Select 'EKS'
3. Under Actions: Select 'All EKS Actions'
4. Under Resources: Either select 'All resources' or Add ARN
5. Click on Review Policy
6. Type the name for the policy & create the policy.

Now, associate this policy to the user account. 
This should solve the issue & you should be able to create the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this structure

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "CDKDeployerPolicy",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cloudformation:CreateStack",
            "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
            "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
            "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
            "cloudformation:GetTemplate",
            "cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet",
            "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
            "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
            "cloudformation:DeleteStack"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

With the recent updates in AWS, the following inline policy will also work.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example policy that grants the necessary permissions to perform the cloudformation:CreateChangeSet action on the aws-ses-serverless-dev CloudFormation stack:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCreateChangeSet",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:030198164798:stack/aws-ses-serverless-dev/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can add this policy to the ses-smtp-user.20230320-141906 IAM user by following these steps:

1. Open the AWS Management Console and go to the IAM service.
2. List In the left sidebar, click on "Users" and find the
   ses-smtp-user.20230320-141906 user.
3. Click on the user to open its
   details page. Click on the "Permissions" tab.
4. Click on the "Add
   inline policy" button to create a new policy.
5. In the policy editor,
   select the "JSON" tab and paste the example policy shown above.
   Click    on the "Review policy" button to review the policy.
6. Give the policy a    name and click on the "Create policy" button to
   create the policy and    attach it to the user.

After adding the policy to the ses-smtp-user.20230320-141906 IAM user, try deploying your Serverless stack again and see if the issue will resolved.