# ValidationError:Stack [CDKToolKit] doesn't not exist

Tags: aws-cdk

When follow this [Github case:amazon-textract-serverless-large-scale-document-processing](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-serverless-large-scale-document-processing)  to execute `cdk bootstrap`, an error message shows when "CDKToolkit:creating CloudFormation changset..." as "ValidationError: Stack [CDKToolkit] does not exist."

Used to refer to this [Stack Overflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237218/user-is-not-authorized-to-perform-cloudformationcreatestack) to update policy for DescribeStack, DescribeChangeset and Createchangeset already.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Would like to know what need to do more to proceed.

Comment: I run `npm install` again and some warn messages like "No repositories field." https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-serverless-large-scale-document-processing/issues/3#issuecomment-502293493

Comment: If someone knows whether I can find the error message `ValidationError:Stack[CdkTookit] does not exist. ` somewhere in these [codes](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/tree/master/packages/aws-cdk)

Comment: Use Github search function and needs to figure out when executes row 241 to 266 of [cdk.ts](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/blob/d0e19d50f5fc1459cea66b309aaa9fe18a3d9618/packages/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.ts), why row 68`print(`%s: creating CloudFormation changeset...`, colors.bold(deployName));` of [deploy-stack.ts](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/blob/d0e19d50f5fc1459cea66b309aaa9fe18a3d9618/packages/aws-cdk/lib/api/deploy-stack.ts) would be executed.

Answer (score 3):

Checking AWS CloudFormation console and learned the status of "CDK Toolkit" stack suspended by "In review process". Learned from this [Stack Overflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394040/aws-cloud-formation-stuck-in-review-in-progress) so deleted that stack and run `cdk bootstrap` in command line again then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are testing in a test AWS account, can you trying giving the user account admin rights just to test and make sure it is not a permissions issues. I see you are giving account cloudformation permissions, but it does a lot more than that. It needs to create IAM roles, and create many additional resources.

Comment: I tried and the error code/message now `ValidationError: Stack [CDKToolkit] does not exist.]`@user3573411